# how to prevent last item in floating items to displace the next row?

Tags: css

We are involved in a website that requires items to be floated , all items are good but when adding (advertising items) an error occurs .

The advertising items appears randomly , some times the adv. item becomes in the end of a row

this causes displacement to the next row

Any help ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide us your code so we can see how is html/css formed so we can provide some solutions to your problem.

Comment: here you are the site where the problem happens : http://www.tofav.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can define float property to this ".compact-site-container{ float:left;}"
If its not working then provide these details - in which resolution and which browser you're getting that problem